# Solving negative IDs? Parent/child relationship

Tags: visual-studio

I am having a parent/child connection in my Execute Package task. I ran into a bug when running this statement. Do you know how to solve the IDs issue?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PackageTaskLog]
   ([PackageLogID]
   ,[SourceName]
   ,[SourceID]
   ,[StartDateTime]
   ,[EndDateTime])
VALUES
( -1 -- PackageLogID
   ,'Parent container'--SourceName
   ,'DD38A23A-E991-4C29-BEA9-B7E1966F0FD4'--SourceID
   ,'2020-03-26 02:00:03.750' -- StartDateTime
   ,'2020-03-26 02:00:04.287' -- EndDateTime
);
```

Comment: What bug? What error message?

Comment: A negative id is perfectly fine, as surrogate keys have no inherent meaning. Any value is equally valid. What problem have you found?